# How to generate Proxy class for WCF in Xamarin in MAC?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.mac

I need to generate proxy class for a WCF service. I got in Windows is with command "SLsvcUtil.exe", however I need to do it in MAC. I have Xamarin Studio running.

Any idea where is the utility in MAC to generate WCF Proxy Class?

Thanks!

Comment: um, Nevermind, looks like this tool is part of Microsoft SDK (Installed on Windows Machine) So I would need to generate my proxy in Windows and send it to my MAC. Wondering if there is a similar utility in Xamarin suite to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Mono does install `svcutil`.

Since you are using the "Silverlight" enabled `svcutil` you can try using the `moonlight` option(?)... I do not use this, so just a guess...

```
Mono service contract conversion tool  0.1.0.0 - Copyright (C) 2006 Novell, Inc.

Usage: svcutil [options] [metadataPath* | metadataUrl* | assemblyPath*]
Options:
  -a, --async                Generate async methods.
      --config=VALUE         Configuration file names to generate.
  -i, --internal             Generate types as internal.
  -l, --language=LANGUAGE    Specify target code LANGUAGE. Default is 'csharp'.
      --monotouch            Generate MonoTouch client. (This option may vanish)
      --moonlight            Generate moonlight client. (This option may vanish)
  -n, --namespace=VALUE      Code namespace name to generate.
      --noConfig             Do not generate config file.
      --noLogo               Do not show tool logo.
  -o, --out=VALUE            Output code filename.
  -r, --reference=VALUE      Referenced assembly files.
      --tcv, --targetClientVersion[=VALUE]
                             Indicate target client version. Valid values:
                                 Version35
      --tm, --typedMessage   Generate typed messages.
      --usage                Show usage syntax and exit.
  -V, --version              Display version and licensing information.
  -h, -?, --help             Show this help list.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using svcutil with -a and --monlight (as well without this one) but output is always empty.

Comment: user-mbp:~ user$ svcutil -a --moonlight http://192.168.1.46:1102/MatchWCF.svc?wsdl
Mono service contract conversion tool  0.1.0.0 - Copyright (C)

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://192.168.1.46:1102/MatchWCF.svc?wsdl' using DISCO..
Disco found documents at the following URLs:
- Xml Schema at    http://192.168.1.46:1102/MatchWCF.svc?xsd=xsd1
- Xml Schema at    http://192.168.1.46:1102/MatchWCF.svc?xsd=xsd2
- WSDL document at  http://192.168.1.46:1102/MatchWCF.svc?wsdl
- Xml Schema at    http://192.168.1.46:1102/MatchWCF.svc?xsd=xsd0
Generating files..
output.cs